# Difference between broadcasting operation and one-to-many in RF transceiver

Tags: data

While writing a report on data broadcasting I came across [this](http://roscansat.com/files/data/RXQ2-433.pdf) paper where I found description on broadcast operation and one-to-many as shown below

> broadcast operation; where a single master address many RXQ2 modules
>   concurrently. (using many RXQ2 modules set to the same address)
>
> one-to-many; A network consisting a master and many slaves (the
>   receivers all have the same address)

My question is what is the difference between these two configurations of data transition?

As *broadcast operation* seem to be transmitting data synchronously and as for the *one-to-many* there was nothing to it. I could not find any information on this online as well.

Answer (score 1):

A broadcast operation involves flashing the data just like a notice board, and whoever requires the data, can read it from the node or terminal broadcasting it. Hence, any node which comes in the radio range of the node broadcasting the data, can see the information or data. In case of RF transceiver, if the master is broadcasting, all slaves in its radio range will be able to read the data.

Whereas, in one- to- many operation, also known as multicasting, there is a group formed called multicast group. This group includes all those nodes to which the particular data is intended and hence, this data cannot be read by any other node which is not included in the group even though, it is in the radio range. In multicasting, each data packet from the master consists of an address header which consists of multicast address. This address is common for all members included in the multicast group. So, the packet can only be received or inferred by those members whose address match the packet address header, i.e., this operation provides a sort of authorization to some nodes over the others.